# iPhone Development Certificates

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, certificate

I'm writing a small hobby iPhone app purely for my own use. I do not intend to distribute it to anyone else.

The development certificate expires every week, and sometimes at a very inopportune moment when I need to use the app. So I need to get back to Xcode to refresh and re-install the app every week.

Is there any way to extend the lifetime of the dev certificate? Except paying for a distribution certificate of course.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the certificate has an expiration time of an year. I am not sure why is yours is expiring every week. Maybe you are using 3rd parties for deployment where you submit your certificates or you regenerate them for some reason. If you just deploy on your device using xcode you should use let xcode manage the signing for you. It might make things better for you.

Comment: No, I am using xcode. The 1 year expiring certificate is probably if you are paying for a paid dev cert or enterprise dev cert. That's what I am trying to avoid, I don't want to pay 100$ a year for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange to hear that developer certificate is expiring every week. As from my knowledge,

There are three types of certificates that you might have on your jailbroken iOS 9.2-9.3.3 device, but you’ll only have one installed at any given time:

- A basic signing certificate: free and lasts 7 days
- A paid developer certificate: $99/year and lasts 1 year
- A paid enterprise developer certificate: $299/year and lasts 1 year

The basic signing certificate that lasts 7 days is the most common, and is the one you’ll come across when you jailbreak with the English version of the Pangu jailbreak tool that was released on Friday. You can get this certificate with your Apple ID (or a burner Apple ID) account that isn’t associated with the Apple Developer Program.

Please follow this article to know more about certificates: [what you need to know about developer certificates](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/07/29/what-you-need-to-know-about-the-ios-9-3-3-jailbreak-certificate-expiry/)

Comment: My device is not jailbreaked and I don't intend to do that. I am using xcode to manage certificates. Thanks for your comments, I'll take a look at the link, to see if it can help.