# Is there a way to keep a Flutter app indefinitely installed on my device for free?

Tags: installation, provisioning-profile

I am developing a Flutter application for personal use only, without the intention to distribute it to others. I installed it on my iPhone via USB about a week ago and attempted to open it, receiving an "[AppName] is no longer available" message.

After some cursory research online it seems that this is because the ad-hoc Apple provisioning profile expires after a week. It seems that in order to extend my provisioning lifespan I need a paid Apple developer account.

I do not want to pay a subscription to use an app I do not intend to distribute any time in the foreseeable future. I know that I can reinstall the app on my phone on a weekly basis, but I would like to avoid this. My primary questions are:

1. Is there any way to keep the installed app indefinitely available (or at least > 1 week) on my iPhone without paying any money?
2. If the answer to (1) is "no", will I face the same issue installing on an Android device?

Thanks in advance.

Of note: [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248580/iphone-development-certificates) which is basically a restatement of my query